# regeride netcdf file to template netcdf file resoulution

Tags: wrf, wrf-chem

how can I regrid my NetCDF file into another NetCDF file resolution?
change the file number 1 or 2 or 3 (file1.nc,file2.nc,file3.nc ) into resolution template file (wrfinput_d01.nc) . I have attached my files(number1,2,3 and template file)
wrfinput file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j6SrSOpbrkWXDl2_WK-MGwcm0zKOXV_x/view?usp=sharing

my files 1,2:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-o7TUcPmzsuOYhpry92ROHQuLA1Z5N-x/view?usp=sharing

cdo griddes wrfinput_d01.nc > NEW_GRID_DEF
cdo remapbil,NEW_GRID_DEF file1.nc output.nc

I've done it by cdo, but it shows error
Error (cdfGetSliceSlapDescription): Internal error, variable evi has an unsupported array structure!
What shall I do to solvr this problem?
thank you!

Comment: Can you please [edit] your title and post to correct the typos, to make your question easier to read?  Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

**Disclaimer**: I have not looked at your particular files.

You can regrid the data in Python using the [NetCDF-4 module](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html). If you want to interpolate vertically, you can use the [WRF](https://wrf-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_api/index.html#interpolation-routines) module. And for horizontal interpolation, you can use the [Scipy Interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) module.

Here is how you would go about this regridding.

Let $(\psi_1,\phi_1)$ be the  latitude and longitude of the original data and $(\psi_2,\phi_2)$ of the regridded data. Let $y_1$ be your original data, and $y_2$ be the regridded data.

1. Open the original dataset.
2. Create an interpolation function trained on your original data $f(\psi_1,\phi_1)$ for the data you will regrid.
3. Using the NetCDF module, declare the dimensions, variables, and necessary metadata for your regridded dataset.
4. Use your interpolation function, so you get $y_2=f(\psi_2,\phi_2)$.
5. If necessary, interpolate to your required vertical level.
6. Repeat starting on step 2 for every time for every variable that you want, at every vertical level (if required).